# Why the modules in my project not working correctly?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

My setup:

[image: project-setup]

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm new to modules in C++.
This is the code in my module:

```cpp
export module Module;
export void MyFunc();
```

And this is the code in the .cpp file

```cpp
import Module;
myFunc()
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
E3344 module file mapping for 'Module' is invalid
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Try giving `MyFunc` a body eg `export void MyFunc() {}`  see example here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules  Also check you are compiling with `/std:c++latest`

Answer (score 1):

File mapping may be not correct because `module.ixx` which is the module interface file must be accompanied with `module.cpp` which is the module implementation file. (if you're separating implementation)

However keep in mind VS intellisense may not work as expected regardless with brand new C++20 language features.

This will take time until working properly, you can try with VS 2022 and set `std:c++latest` option to be up to date with intellisense.

Comment: Very weird. Project builds but intellisense doesn't work and shows this error with the latest VS 2022. Unfortunate.

Comment: From my experience intellisense is always behind when new language features are introduced in VS, but in time it adds up as development of the IDE and compiler continues.

Comment: I gave up. They break intellisense and syntax coloring completely and I use them correctly. Maybe in few years from now it's gonna work better.

Comment: Know that if you use new language construct in code then it may break whole intellisense including portion that usually works. A solution is to not use new language features if you depend on intellisense.